# Grout gap - best way to fix?

Tags: grout, gap

I just had a full bathroom reno done and Kerdi board was used on walls, floor, bench and shelves in fully tiled shower; however, I have a gap in the middle of the bottom of the bench where it meets the shower floor. It looks like clear silicone was used over grout but I can stick my nail in the gap so it isn’t “sealed”. I’m not so worried about water damage (maybe a little though) since kerdi board was used but aesthetically it is driving me mad. Anyway, could I just put some grout in the gap to make it less noticeable? Or would caulk work? All the work was just finished about a month ago so I have grout and matching caulk left over - just don’t want to make anything look bad since job was very well done (just this small imperfection). Fixed! (Second pic)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Without a photo, its guess work.

Comment: Shoot, didn’t realize I could add photos. Just updated my original post with image. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase color-matched silicone caulking in the same color of the grout. I’d lay that in to the gap.

Comment: It is always recommended to use elastomeric sealers (i.e. caulk) rather than grout at changes of plane (i.e. corners).

Comment: @kreemoweet thanks! Took that advice and closed it up just now. Added my after pic under original photo. I’m definitely a rookie caulker (maybe used caulk twice in my life) but I think this girl didn’t do too bad of a job :) a little worried that the hole on the left was a weep hole though which I closed. There are a couple others though that are open.